# Finding Valid Link With Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord Bot for the Texas A&M ESports Organization, specifically for the Super Smash Bros Discord channel. I want to implement a functionality where it sends the link to the weekly tournament every week at the same time.

Here are some examples of links to past tournaments:

https://smash.gg/tournament/no-caps-10-11-1-19-rudder-tower-510/details

https://smash.gg/tournament/no-caps-10-4-msc-1400/details

https://smash.gg/tournament/no-caps-9-10-25-19-rudder-tower-601/details

As you can see, the links don't follow an exact pattern that I could hard code in. I was thinking about copying and pasting the link in each week, but that would defeat the purpose of the functionality.

I was thinking that I could look for the most recently created link that followed some sort of general form, as there are similarities between the links, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm using the Discord.js library.

Comment: Is there an API to the smash.gg site? If so you could pull in an array of objects from the posts from the link smash.gg/tournament/ (which is common between all links) and then get the most recent and gets its url. However, that all depends on the fact that the site has an API or not.

Comment: I'll check, thanks!